# How can I decode a file name using command line?

Tags: command-line, filenames, unicode

is it possibile to decode a file name by command line?

Suppose I have the following two files:

- foo.mp3
- bar.mp3

Is there any command line tool that decodes the files names into their UTF-8 values:

- 0x66 0x6F 0x6F 0x2E 0x6D 0x70 0x33
- 0x62 0x61 0x72 0x2E 0x6D 0x70 0x33

Comment: Just a simple point:  You appear to want to show the file contents, not decode the file name.

Comment: @JuliePelletier looks like the question is perfectly clear: how to decode a filename into UTF-8 octets

Comment: For `€` for instance, would you like to see 0x20ac (the Unicode code point of that EURO character) or 0xe2 0x82 0xac (the 3 bytes of the UTF-8 encoding of that EURO character)?

Comment: ...and what to do if the input (file name) isn't a valid UTF-8 byte sequence?

Comment: The target of the question is to get, starting from a file name, the UTF-8 encoded values. So in the case of the € symbol, I expect: 0xe2 0x82 0xac. The solution proposed by Stéphane, based on iconv, tells you if a file name is well encoded or not

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard (POSIX/Unix) command to get the byte values as hex numbers  is `od`.

```
file=foo.mp3
printf %s "$file" | od -An -vtx1
```

Which gives an output similar to:

```
 66 6f 6f 2e 6d 70 33
```

`$file` above contains an arbitrary array of (non-NUL for shells other than `zsh`) *bytes*. The character encoding doesn't enter in consideration.

If you want `$file` to contain an array of *characters* (so in the locale's encoding) and you want to get the Unicode code points for each of them as hexadecimal numbers, on a Little-Endian system, you could do:

```
printf %s "$file" | iconv -t UTF-32LE | od -An -vtx4
```

See also:

```
printf %s "$file" | recode ..dump
```

Or:

```
printf %s "$file" | uconv -x hex/unicode
printf %s "$file" | uconv -x '([:Any:])>&hex/unicode($1)\n'
```

If you wanted the byte values as hex numbers of the UTF-8 encoding of those characters:

```
printf %s "$file" | iconv -t UTF-8 | od -An -vtx1
```

For something like `foo.mp3` that contains only ASCII characters, they're all going to be equivalent.

Comment: You mean `UTF-32LE` instead of `UTF32LE`?

Comment: @cuonglm, on my system, both works. But I've changed it to UTF-32LE if that's more portable.

Comment: Yep, at least in my OSX El Capital, `UTF32LE` does not work.

Comment: I tried to use UTF-32LE but it seems not supported:"iconv: conversion to `UTF-32LE' is not supported". It's strange because "iconv --list | grep UTF" returns both UTF-32LE and UTF-32BE. Anyway, specifying UTF-8 works fine

Comment: I'm a bit "out of context", but about the choices of unicode out there, I want to point people reading this answer to a good read : http://utf8everywhere.org/ ... spread the word! ^^

Answer (score 5):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -CA -le 'print join " ", map { sprintf "0x%X", $_ } unpack "U*" for @ARGV' \
  foo.mp3 bar.mp3 cường
0x66 0x6F 0x6F 0x2E 0x6D 0x70 0x33
0x62 0x61 0x72 0x2E 0x6D 0x70 0x33
0x63 0x1B0 0x1EDD 0x6E 0x67
```

If you store those list of filenames in a file, then:

```
perl -CI -lne 'print join " ", map { sprintf "0x%X", $_ } unpack "U*"' <file
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be done with a simple Perl script:

```
perl -we 'foreach my $file (glob("*")) { 
   printf "0x%02X ", ord($_) foreach split//, $file; print "\n" }; '
```

resulting in output similar to yours when the directory contains files `foo.mp3` and `bar.mp3`:

```
0x62 0x61 0x72 0x2E 0x6D 0x70 0x33 
0x66 0x6F 0x6F 0x2E 0x6D 0x70 0x33
```

(I think `glob()` sorts the names.)

Explanation:

```
foreach my $file (glob("*")) {   # loop over all filenames in current directory 
    printf "0x%02X ", ord($_)    # take the character as a number, and print in hex
      foreach split//, $file;    # .. after splitting the filename to characters
    print "\n";                  # add a newline
}
```

<sub>(* except those that start with a dot)</sub>

This will just print the actual bytes in the filenames, as they are stored on the file system. If you have files whose names are not in UTF-8, the script will not convert them.

You could also do something like piping the output of `ls` to `od` or `xxd`, which would also work with other data than lists of file names, but would bring [all the problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) that come with reading `ls`, and it would be hard to get the file names separated to different lines.

Comment: Note that this doesn't print the unicode codepoint of the unicode characters.

Comment: @cuonglm Like it says on the lid, it will print the actual bytes, as they are stored on file system. It's a bit hard to say what they want, given the examples in the question only contain plain ASCII characters.

Comment: Hi ilkkachu, first of all thanks for your answer. The purpouse of the question is to be able to decode every kind of UTF-8 characters, not only ASCII set

Comment: And pass the a filename pattern (glob string) to the above perl to only show files that match the pattern desired.

Answer (score 4):

With plain Bash:

```
a=abcdefghij    
for ((i=0;i<${#a};i++));do printf %02X \'${a:$i:1};done
6162636465666768696A
```

Customize the `printf` format to suit your needs.

Comment: This will fail for unicode characters.